# Best or easiest way to represent 2D array

Tags: arrays, prolog

What is the Best way to represent 2D arrays in Prolog ?

So that I can get/set values by x,y coordinates.

List of lists seems cumbersome ! but if there is no ready solution and is easier to implement...

Red that maybe Tuple of tuples may be easier to implement, because of arg/setarg ?

---

this is what i got so far ... just need the array creation :

```
get(X,Y,Ary,Val) :-
   arg(X,Ary,Row),
   arg(Y,Row,Val).

set(X,Y,Ary,Val) :-
   arg(X,Ary,Row),
   setarg(Y,Row,Val).
```

---

not sure i can skip the list part ?

```
fill([], _, 0).
fill([X|Xs], X, N) :-
   succ(N0, N),
   fill(Xs, X, N0).

new_ary1d(Size,Sym,Ary) :-
   fill(A,Sym,Size),
   Ary =.. [a1 | A].

new_ary2d(Rows,Cols,Sym,Ary) :-     
   new_ary1d(Cols,Sym,A1),
   fill(A2,A1,Rows),
   Ary =.. [a2 | A2].
```

---

the list transformation above didnt work corectly, so
using @slago template I ended up with [this](https://myriad.website/arrays-in-prolog/)
thanks

Comment: When the length is pre-known, use a term instead of a list, for performance. Example: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/queens.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
matrix_new(Nrows, Ncols, Matrix) :-
    length(Matrix, Nrows),
    length(Row, Ncols),
    maplist(=(0), Row),
    maplist(=(Row), Matrix).

matrix_get(Matrix, I, J, Element) :-
    nth1(I, Matrix, Row),
    nth1(J, Row, Element).

matrix_set(Matrix, I, J, Element, NewMatrix) :-
    nth1(I, Matrix, Row, RestOfMatrix),
    nth1(J, Row, _, RestOfRow),
    nth1(J, NewRow, Element, RestOfRow),
    nth1(I, NewMatrix, NewRow, RestOfMatrix).
```

Example:

```
?- matrix_new(2,3,M0), matrix_set(M0,1,1,10,M1), matrix_set(M1,2,3,60,M2), matrix_get(M2,1,1,X11).
M0 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
M1 = [[10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
M2 = [[10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 60]],
X11 = 10.
```

**EDIT** It is **not recommended** to create predicates with side effects. Anyway, a possible solution using terms is as follows:

```
m_new(Nrows, Ncols, Matrix) :-
    functor(Matrix, array, Nrows),
    functor(Row, array, Ncols),
    forall(arg(J,Row,_), nb_setarg(J,Row,0)),
    forall(arg(I,Matrix,_), nb_setarg(I,Matrix,Row)).

m_set(Matrix, I, J, Value) :-
    arg(I, Matrix, Row),
    setarg(J, Row, Value).

m_get(Matrix, I, J, Value) :-
    arg(I, Matrix, Row),
    arg(J, Row, Value).
```

Example:

```
?- m_new(2,3,M), m_set(M,1,1,9), m_set(M,2,3,8), m_get(M,1,1,X11), m_get(M,2,3,X23), m_get(M,1,2,X12).
M = array(array(9, 0, 0), array(0, 0, 8)),
X11 = 9,
X23 = 8,
X12 = 0.
```

Comment: clever ... how can i adapt matrix_new to terms

Comment: @sten See EDIT in my answer, please!

Comment: thanks.. used your solution as a template.. so i have both 1d and 2d .. https://myriad.website/arrays-in-prolog/   ... next step what i needed 2D ary composed of squares ;), rather than cells